# pyTelegramBotAPI python-telegram-bot-calendar v1.0.2 Помогите пересобрать календарь

Tags: python, telebot

Помогите пересобрать `python-telegram-bot-calendar` - хочу добавить часы и минуты, вроде все сделал, но где-то ошибка, не могу понять.

Выдаёт:

> File
> "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\telegram_bot_calendar\detailed.py",
> line 50, in _process  minute = int(params['minute']) KeyError:
> 'minute'

`base.py`. Добавил часы + минуты:

```
import json
import random
from datetime import date

from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

from telegram_bot_calendar.static import MONTHS, DAYS_OF_WEEK, HOURS, MINUTES_OF_HOUR

calendar.setfirstweekday(calendar.MONDAY)

CB_CALENDAR = "cbcal"

YEAR = 'y'
MONTH = 'm'
DAY = 'd'
HOUR = "h"
MINUTE = "mi"
SELECT = "s"
GOTO = "g"
NOTHING = "n"
LSTEP = {'y': 'year', 'm': 'month', 'd': 'day', 'h': 'hour', 'mi': 'minute'}


class TelegramCalendar:
    months = MONTHS
    days_of_week = DAYS_OF_WEEK
    hours = HOURS
    minutes_of_hour = MINUTES_OF_HOUR
    prev_button = "<<"
    next_button = ">>"
    middle_button_minute = "{hour} {day} {month} {year}"
    middle_button_hour = "{day} {month} {year}"
    middle_button_day = "{month} {year}"
    middle_button_month = "{year}"
    middle_button_year = " "
    back_to_button = "<<< {name}"
    empty_nav_button = "×"
    empty_day_button = " "
    empty_month_button = " "
    empty_year_button = " "
    size_year = 2
    size_year_column = 2
    size_month = 3
    size_day = 7
    size_hour = 4
    size_minute = 60
    size_additional_buttons = 2
    _keyboard = None
    step = None

    def __init__(self, calendar_id=0, current_date=None, additional_buttons=None, locale='ru', min_date=None,
                 max_date=None, **kwargs):

        if current_date is None: current_date = date.today()
        if min_date is None: min_date = date(1, 1, 1)
        if max_date is None: max_date = date(2999, 12, 31)

        self.calendar_id = calendar_id
        self.current_date = current_date
        self.locale = locale

        self.min_date = min_date
        self.max_date = max_date

        if not additional_buttons: additional_buttons = []
        self.additional_buttons = rows(additional_buttons, self.size_additional_buttons)

        self.prev_button_year = self.prev_button
        self.next_button_year = self.next_button
        self.prev_button_month = self.prev_button
        self.next_button_month = self.next_button
        self.prev_button_day = self.prev_button
        self.next_button_day = self.next_button
        self.prev_button_hour = self.prev_button
        self.next_button_hour = self.next_button
        self.prev_button_minute = self.prev_button
        self.next_button_minute = self.next_button

        self.nav_buttons = {
            YEAR: [self.prev_button_year, self.middle_button_year, self.next_button_year],
            MONTH: [self.prev_button_month, self.middle_button_month, self.next_button_month],
            DAY: [self.prev_button_day, self.middle_button_day, self.next_button_day],
            HOUR: [self.prev_button_hour, self.middle_button_hour, self.next_button_hour],
            MINUTE: [self.prev_button_minute, self.middle_button_minute, self.next_button_minute],
        }

    @staticmethod
    def func(calendar_id=0):
        def inn(callback):
            start = CB_CALENDAR + "_" + str(calendar_id)
            return callback.data.startswith(start)

        return inn

    def build(self):
        if not self._keyboard:
            self._build()
        return self._keyboard, self.step

    def process(self, call_data):
        return self._process(call_data)

    def _build(self, *args, **kwargs):

    def _process(self, call_data, *args, **kwargs):


    def _build_callback(self, action, step, data, *args, is_random=False, **kwargs):
        if action == NOTHING:
            params = [CB_CALENDAR, str(self.calendar_id), action]
        else:
            data = list(map(str, data.timetuple()[:3]))
            params = [CB_CALENDAR, str(self.calendar_id), action, step] + data

        salt = "_" + str(random.randint(1, 1e18)) if is_random else ""

        return "_".join(params) + salt

    def _build_button(self, text, action, step=None, data=None, is_random=False, **kwargs):
        return {
            'text': text,
            'callback_data': self._build_callback(action, step, data, is_random=is_random)
        }

    def _build_keyboard(self, buttons):
        return json.dumps({"inline_keyboard": buttons + self.additional_buttons})

    def _valid_date(self, d):
        return self.min_date <= d <= self.max_date

    def _get_period(self, step, start, diff, *args, **kwargs):
        lstep = LSTEP[step] + "s"
        dates = []

        empty_before = 0
        empty_after = 0

        for i in range(diff):
            n_date = start + relativedelta(**{lstep: i})
            if self.min_date > max_date(n_date, step):
                empty_before += 1
            elif self.max_date < min_date(n_date, step):
                empty_after += 1
            else:
                dates.append(n_date)
        return [None] * empty_before + dates + [None] * empty_after

def rows(buttons, row_size):
    return [buttons[i:i + row_size] for i in range(0, max(len(buttons) - row_size, 0) + 1, row_size)]

def max_date(d, step):
    if step == YEAR:
        return d.replace(month=12, day=31)
    elif step == MONTH:
        return d.replace(day=calendar.monthrange(d.year, d.month)[1])
    else:
        return d

def min_date(d, step):
    if step == YEAR:
        return d.replace(month=1, day=1)
    elif step == MONTH:
        return d.replace(day=1)
    else:
        return d
```

`detailed.py`. Добавил часы + минуты:

```
from telegram_bot_calendar.base import *

STEPS = {YEAR: MONTH, MONTH: DAY, DAY: HOUR, HOUR: MINUTE}

PREV_STEPS = {MINUTE: HOUR, HOUR: DAY, DAY: MONTH, MONTH: YEAR, YEAR: YEAR}
PREV_ACTIONS = {MINUTE: GOTO, HOUR:GOTO, DAY: GOTO, MONTH: GOTO, YEAR: NOTHING}


class DetailedTelegramCalendar(TelegramCalendar):
   first_step = MONTH

   def __init__(self, calendar_id=0, current_date=None, additional_buttons=None, locale='ru',
                min_date=None,
                max_date=None, **kwargs):
       super(DetailedTelegramCalendar, self).__init__(calendar_id, current_date=current_date,
                                                      additional_buttons=additional_buttons, locale=locale,
                                                      min_date=min_date, max_date=max_date)

   def _build(self, step=None, **kwargs):
       if not step:
           step = self.first_step

       self.step = step
       if step == YEAR:
           self._build_years()
       elif step == MONTH:
           self._build_months()
       elif step == DAY:
           self._build_days()
       elif step == HOUR:
           self._build_hours()
       elif step == MINUTE:
           self._build_minutes()

   def _process(self, call_data, *args, **kwargs):
       params = call_data.split("_")
       params = dict(
           zip(["start", "calendar_id", "action", "step", "year", "month", "day", "hour", "minute"][:len(params)], params))

       if params['action'] == NOTHING:
           return None, None, None
       step = params['step']

       year = int(params['year'])
       month = int(params['month'])
       day = int(params['day'])
       hour = int(params['hour'])
       minute = int(params['minute'])
       self.current_date = date(year, month, day, hour, minute)

       if params['action'] == GOTO:
           self._build(step=step)
           return None, self._keyboard, step

       if params['action'] == SELECT:
           if step in STEPS:
               self._build(step=STEPS[step])
               return None, self._keyboard, STEPS[step]
           else:
               return self.current_date, None, step

   def _build_years(self, *args, **kwargs):
       years_num = self.size_year * self.size_year_column

       start = self.current_date - relativedelta(years=(years_num - 1) // 2)
       years = self._get_period(YEAR, start, years_num)
       years_buttons = rows(
           [
               self._build_button(d.year if d else self.empty_year_button, SELECT if d else NOTHING, YEAR, d,
                                  is_random=True)
               for d in years
           ],
           self.size_year
       )

       nav_buttons = self._build_nav_buttons(YEAR, diff=relativedelta(years=years_num),
                                             mind=max_date(start, YEAR),
                                             maxd=min_date(start + relativedelta(years=years_num - 1), YEAR))

       self._keyboard = self._build_keyboard(years_buttons + nav_buttons)

   def _build_months(self, *args, **kwargs):
       start = self.current_date.replace(month=1)
       months = self._get_period(MONTH, self.current_date.replace(month=1), 12)
       months_buttons = rows(
           [
               self._build_button(
                   self.months[self.locale][d.month - 1] if d else self.empty_month_button,
                   SELECT if d else NOTHING, 
                   MONTH, d, is_random=True 
               )
               for d in months
           ],
           self.size_month)

       nav_buttons = self._build_nav_buttons(MONTH, diff=relativedelta(months=12),
                                             mind=max_date(start, MONTH),
                                             maxd=min_date(start.replace(month=12), MONTH))

       self._keyboard = self._build_keyboard(months_buttons + nav_buttons)

   def _build_days(self, *args, **kwargs):
       days_num = monthrange(self.current_date.year, self.current_date.month)[1]

       start = self.current_date.replace(day=1)
       days = self._get_period(DAY, start, days_num)

       days_buttons = rows(
           [
               self._build_button(d.day if d else self.empty_day_button, SELECT if d else NOTHING, DAY, d,
                                  is_random=True)
               for d in days
           ],
           self.size_day
       )

       days_of_week_buttons = [[
           self._build_button(self.days_of_week[self.locale][i], NOTHING) for i in range(7)
       ]]

    
       nav_buttons = self._build_nav_buttons(DAY, diff=relativedelta(day=1),
                                             maxd=max_date(start, Day),
                                             mind=min_date(start + relativedelta(days=days_num - 1), Day))

       self._keyboard = self._build_keyboard(days_of_week_buttons + days_buttons + nav_buttons)

   def _build_hours(self, *args, **kwargs):
       start = self.current_date.replace(hour=1)
       hours = self._get_period(HOUR, self.current_date.replace(hour=1), 24)
       months_buttons = rows(
           [
               self._build_button(
                   self.hours[self.locale][d.hour - 1] if d else self.empty_hour_button,
                   SELECT if d else NOTHING,
                   HOUR, d, is_random=True  
               )
               for d in hours
           ],
           self.size_hour)

       nav_buttons = self._build_nav_buttons(HOUR, diff=relativedelta(hours=24),
                                             mind=max_date(start, HOUR),
                                             maxd=min_date(start.replace(hour=24), HOUR))

       self._keyboard = self._build_keyboard(hours_buttons + nav_buttons)

   def _build_minutes(self, *args, **kwargs):
       start = self.current_date.replace(minute=1)
       minutes = self._get_period(MINUTE, self.current_date.replace(minute=1), 60)
       minutes_buttons = rows(
           [
               self._build_button(
                   self.minutes[self.locale][d.minute - 1] if d else self.empty_minute_button,
                   SELECT if d else NOTHING,  
                   MINUTE, d, is_random=True  
               )
               for d in minutes
           ],
           self.size_minute)

       nav_buttons = self._build_nav_buttons(MINUTE, diff=relativedelta(minutes=60),
                                             mind=max_date(start, MINUTE),
                                             maxd=min_date(start.replace(minute=12), MINUTE))

       self._keyboard = self._build_keyboard(minutes_buttons + nav_buttons)

   def _build_nav_buttons(self, step, diff, mind, maxd, *args, **kwargs):

       text = self.nav_buttons[step]

       sld = list(map(str, self.current_date.timetuple()[:3]))
       data = [sld[0], self.months[self.locale][int(sld[1]) - 1], sld[2]]
       data = dict(zip(["year", "month", "day", "hour", "minute"], data))
       prev_page = self.current_date - diff
       next_page = self.current_date + diff

       prev_exists = mind - relativedelta(**{LSTEP[step] + "s": 1}) >= self.min_date
       next_exists = maxd + relativedelta(**{LSTEP[step] + "s": 1}) <= self.max_date

       return [[
           self._build_button(text[0].format(**data) if prev_exists else self.empty_nav_button,
                              GOTO if prev_exists else NOTHING, step, prev_page, is_random=True),
           self._build_button(text[1].format(**data),
                              PREV_ACTIONS[step], PREV_STEPS[step], self.current_date, is_random=True),
           self._build_button(text[2].format(**data) if next_exists else self.empty_nav_button,
                              GOTO if next_exists else NOTHING, step, next_page, is_random=True),
       ]]

   def _get_period(self, step, start, diff, *args, **kwargs):
       if step != DAY:
           return super(DetailedTelegramCalendar, self)._get_period(step, start, diff, *args, **kwargs)

       dates = []
       cl = calendar.monthcalendar(start.year, start.month)
       for week in cl:
           for day in week:
               if day != 0 and self._valid_date(date(start.year, start.month, day)):
                   dates.append(date(start.year, start.month, day))
               else:
                   dates.append(None)

       return dates
```

`_init_.py`. Добавил часы + минуты:

```
from telegram_bot_calendar.whour import WHourTelegramCalendar
from telegram_bot_calendar.wday import WDayTelegramCalendar
from telegram_bot_calendar.wmonth import WMonthTelegramCalendar
from telegram_bot_calendar.wyear import WYearTelegramCalendar
```

`static.py`. Добавил часы + минуты:

````
    'en': ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
    'eo': ["jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "maj", "jun", "jul", "aŭg", "sep", "okt", "nov", "dec"],
    'ru': ["янв", "фев", "мар", "апр", "май", "июн", "июл", "авг", "сен", "окт", "ноя", "дек"],
}

DAYS_OF_WEEK = {
    'en': ["M", "T", "W", "T", "F", "S", "S"],
    'eo': ["L", "M", "M", "Ĵ", "V", "S", "D"],
    'ru': ["П", "В", "С", "Ч", "П", "С", "В"],
}

HOURS = {
    'en': ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13",
         "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23"],
    'eo': ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13",
         "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23"],
    'ru': ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13",
         "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23"],
}

MINUTES_OF_HOUR = {
    'en': ["00", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11",
            "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23",
            "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35",
             "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47",
              "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59"],
    'eo': ["00", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11",
            "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23",
            "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35",
             "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47",
              "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59"],
    'ru': ["00", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11",
            "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23",
            "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35",
             "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47",
              "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59"],
} ```

`wyear.py`. Оставил как есть:

``` from telegram_bot_calendar.base import MONTH
from telegram_bot_calendar.detailed import DetailedTelegramCalendar


class WYearTelegramCalendar(DetailedTelegramCalendar):
    first_step = MONTH
````

`wmonth.py`. Оставил как есть:

```
from telegram_bot_calendar.detailed import DetailedTelegramCalendar


class WMonthTelegramCalendar(DetailedTelegramCalendar):
    first_step = DAY
```

`whour.py`. Добавил новым:

```
from telegram_bot_calendar.detailed import DetailedTelegramCalendar


class WHourTelegramCalendar(DetailedTelegramCalendar):
    first_step = MINUTE
```

`wday.py`. Добавил новым:

```
from telegram_bot_calendar.detailed import DetailedTelegramCalendar


class WDayTelegramCalendar(DetailedTelegramCalendar):
    first_step = HOUR
```

Comment: Если бы вы перевели сообщение ошибки, вы бы узнали, что проблема в файле `detailed.py` в 50 строчке, в функции `_process minute = int(params['minute'])`. Но вы почему-то этого не сделали

Comment: Перевод то я осилил, в чем проблема не пойму! Что ему не нравится то)? Вроде все там ок

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том, что у функции `date` из модуля `datetime` нет аргументов `hour`, `minute`.  Если вам необходима дата: `2021-10-01 04:17:00`, используйте `datetime` вместо `date`. Если нужна дата `Tuesday, 21. November 2006 04:30PM`, то используйте `strftime`.

Изучите подробно документацию на модуль `datetime` и выберите необходимый вариант.

Comment: поэтому можно взять из `datetime`

`from datetime import datetime

x = datetime.now()
print(str(x.year) + '-' + str(x.month) + '-' + str(x.day) + ' ' + str(x.hour) + ':' + str(x.minute))`

Comment: Как всегда)!!! Низкий поклон! Благодарю!!!!